# Angular2 - NodeJs Facebook Login - Password issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, facebook-login

I have an application which is built in the following: `Angular 2`, `Nodejs` and `Mongodb`

The flow is as follows:

1. `Angular 2` calls `API's` located in `Node js` server
2. `Node js` connects to `Mongodb` and performs queries which return results.

I'm currently working on the register page, I'm allowing the user to either register with an email and password or login with facebook.

Sign in with Email and Password is working perfectly fine, however I've successfully implemented the following `npm` package into my `Angular 2` project.

[Facebook login ng2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-facebook-sdk#2-add-the-facebook-javascript-sdk-to-your-indexhtml)

The issue I have is when the user decides to login with `Facebook` obviously I do not have access to their password, and my user account collection within `Mongodb` is of course expecting a password to be supplied.

I can of course pass in the userId (which is passed back from the facebook login) as the password which will of course be encrypted to over come this issue, but if the user then decides to reset their password the above will be redundant.

Has anyone experienced this before? if so how did you overcome it?

Many thanks.